# PostgreSQL JOIN with array type with array elements order, how to implement?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I have two tables in database:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 ... some other fields
);
```

This table contains come data row with unique ID.

```
CREATE TABLE some_chosen_data_in_order(
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 id_items INTEGER[],
);
```

This table contains array type field. Each row contains values of IDs from table `items` in specific order. For example: `{2,4,233,5}`.

Now, I want to get data from table `items` for chosen row from table `some_chosen_data_in_order` with order for elements in array type.

My attempt was JOIN:

```
SELECT I.* FROM items AS I 
JOIN some_chosen_data_in_order AS S ON I.id = ANY(S.id_items) WHERE S.id = ?
```

Second attempt was subquery like:

```
SELECT I.* FROM items AS I 
WHERE I.id = ANY 
(ARRAY[SELECT S.id_items FROM some_chosen_data_in_order  WHERE id = ?])
```

But none of them keep IDs in the same order as in array field. Could you help me, how to get data from `items` table with correspond with array IDs order from `some_chosen_data_in_order` table for specific row?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,2,3,5]) item_id
LEFT JOIN items t on t.id=item_id
```

The above query select items from `items` table with ids: 1,2,3,2,3,5 in that order.

Comment: unnest() is a really cool trick! I had a list of ID's from a customer and needed to join against them but wanted to find a way to do it w/o a temp table. You can join (select unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3])) as idlist and it works like a champ. thanks!

Comment: @apinstein can you please show me the query? still dint get it

Comment: If you want to join two tables with each other you could for instance use `SELECT b.*, a.item_id FROM (SELECT unnest(array_column_in_table_a) item_id FROM table_a) as a
RIGHT JOIN table_b b on b.id=a.item_id;`

Comment: I needed to join to tables, but the above comment didn't work for me, but this did: `SELECT * FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON b.id = ANY(a.array_column_in_table_a);`, thanks to https://www.garysieling.com/blog/postgres-join-on-an-array-field

Comment: This doesn't match the question, why was it chosen?

Answer (score 56):

Probably normalizing your table would be the best advice I can give you.

The int_array contrib module has an idx function that will give you the int's index position in the array. Also there is an idx function on the [snippets wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Index) that works for array's of any data types.

```
SELECT i.*, idx(id_items, i.id) AS idx
FROM some_chosen_data_in_order s
JOIN items i ON i.id = ANY(s.id_items)
ORDER BY idx(id_items, i.id)
```

Comment: Works, thanks.  The order by clause works with just `idx` as well.

Comment: `where s.id = ?` -- an id number

Answer (score 8):

```
select distinct on (some_chosen_data_in_order.id)
  some_chosen_data_in_order.*,
   array_to_json( array_agg(row_to_json( items))
  over ( partition by some_chosen_data_in_order.id ))
from some_chosen_data_in_order
  left join items on items.id = any (some_chosen_data_in_order.id_items)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like functions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489805/642096):

```sql
SELECT jt.*
FROM (
     SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT dupes_column) AS unique_vals
     FROM dupes_table
) q
LEFT JOIN joined_table jt
ON jt.id = ANY(q.unique_vals);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT I.* FROM items AS I 
WHERE I.id IN (SELECT UNNEST(id_items) FROM some_chosen_data_in_order 
(ARRAY[SELECT S.id_items FROM some_chosen_data_in_order  WHERE id = ?])
```

Comment: When adding code as answer, then add a bit explanation to your answer for future readers..