# PostgreSQL JOIN with array type with array elements

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I have two tables tags and users

Table Name:  tags

```
| id | name  |  
| 1  | one   |   
| 2  | two   |   
| 3  | three |   
| 4  | four  |   
| 5  | five  |
```

Table Name:  users

```
| id | fname | tags      |  
| 1  | Ram   | {1,5}     |
| 2  | Sham  | {1,2,3,4} |
| 3  | Bham  | {1,3}     |
| 4  | Kam   | {5,2}     |
| 5  | Lam   | {4,2}     |
```

Expected output:

```
| id | fname | tags                  |
| 1  | Ram   | one, five             |
| 2  | Sham  | one, two, three, four |
| 3  | Bham  | one, three            |
| 4  | Kam   | five, two             |
| 5  | Lam   | four, two             |
```

Trial-1 : using JOIN

```
SELECT I.id, I.fname, I.tags, J.name FROM users I 
JOIN tags J ON J.id = ANY(I.cached_tag_ids) 
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
| id | fname | tags |
| 1  | Ram   | one  |
| 1  | Ram   | five |
```

Expected:

```
| id | fname | tags       |
| 1  | Ram   | one, five  |
```

Comment: IN the first row dont you mean one,five

Comment: yes sorry my mistake

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `tags` should have a `INTEGER[]` type.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
   id SERIAL,
   fname VARCHAR(50),
   tags INTEGER[]
);
```

Then,

```
SELECT I.id, I.fname, array_agg(J.name) 
FROM users I 
LEFT JOIN tags J 
ON J.id = ANY(I.tags) 
GROUP BY fname,I.id ORDER BY id
```

should work. See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0d508/1)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486725/postgresql-join-with-array-type-with-array-elements-order-how-to-implement) may help.

Comment: I am using the same query to create the users table...

SELECT I.id, I.fname, I.tags, J.name FROM users I JOIN tags J ON J.id = ANY(I.tags) LIMIT 1 

The SELECT query you have given returns

    | id | fname | tags |
    | 1  | Ram   | one  |
    | 1  | Ram   | two  |

Comment: @Umega added sqlfiddle

Comment: @Umega use a left join then